# Joining on Int to String in EF4.1 & SQLCE

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, casting, sql-server-ce

I have two database tables:

- 'MyTable' which has a standard auto-incrementing primary key integer field.
- 'UserAccess' table is a mapping table that contains links to all systems via a composite key join.

**MyTable**:

```
ID              int    
IsDeleted       bit    
Email           varchar(255)
```

**UserAccess**:

```
UserID          guid    
ProviderID      int    
ProviderUserID  varchar(255)
```

Both tables are set up in my application via **Entity Framework 4.1 Code First**.

The primary table (my system/provider) has its own ID (e.g. 42). It can find if a user has access by finding if they have a record in the table for the `ProviderID` of 42.

My problem comes when trying to find out who a particular record in `MyTable` belongs to by mapping the ProviderUserID (varchar) to the primary key of my table (int). I can't change the ProviderUserID as there are some systems that use strings as their primary keys (URLs / emails / etc).

This problem can be solved with SQL simply:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable AS M
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserAccess AS U ON U.ProviderID = 42 AND M.ID = U.ProviderUserID
```

But in Entity Framework and more specifically, a combination of LINQ to Entities and **SQL Compact Edition** - I'm unable to do type casting at runtime.

The obvious candidates like `Convert.ToString()` and `Convert.ToInt()` don't work as it's L2E. And the `SqlFunctions.Convert` isn't available as this is SQL CE.

This problem probably goes away if I go off SQL CE and can use the `SqlFunctions`, but as CE is quite useful for quickly building a working DbContext for Unit Testing with - I was less excited about doing that - though it's a possibility if I can't find a way around this.

I've tried a number of ways, and got close with different failings each time. The one below would work great if both types (`UserAccess.ProviderUserID` and `MyTable.ID`) were of the same type - but they aren't :)

```
var data = (from m in DB.MyTable
            let userID = DB.UserAccess.Where(x => x.ProviderID == 42).FirstOrDefault(x => p.ID == x.ProviderUserID).UserID
            select new DomainModel()
            {
               ID = m.ID
               Email = m.Email,
               IsDeleted = m.IsDeleted,
               UserID =userID,
            });
```

Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong or what I can do to battle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is not the ideal solution, it's the one I've settled on for the time being.

- I've changed the database used by the unit testing to a SQL Express database and that enabled me to use the SqlFunctions class and the methods in it.

I was then able to tweak the query to look similar to the following:

```
var data = (from m in DB.MyTable
            join i in DB.UserAccess.Where(x => x.ProviderID == 42) on SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)m.ID).Trim() equals i.ProviderUserID into useraccess
            from ua in useraccess.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new DomainModel()
            {
               ID = m.ID
               Email = m.Email,
               IsDeleted = m.IsDeleted,
               UserID = ua.UserID,
            });
```

I'll keep an eye on this question and if there are any better answers I'll happy upvote / change my accepted answer.

p.s. as an aside, the `.Trim()` was added as the initial string conversion was adding buckets full of whitespace to the start of the string.